# While loop wrong output given

Tags: c#, while-loop, points

I have a list of Points `List<Point> newcoor = new List<Point>();` and specific coordinate which is the center of the List of Points. `int centerx, centery;`

What I want to do is **add 1 with centerx and subtract 1 with centery** until it reaches a combination that will match a Point inside a list. Then store that point inside an array. This is my code:

```
List<Point> newcoor = new List<Point>(); // list of points that where the tempx and tempy will be compared to.

//...

Point[] vector = new Point[4];

int x = 0;

while (x <= 3) 
{
    var tempx = centerx + 1; //add 1 to centerx
    var tempy = centerx - 1; //subtrat 1 to centery
    int y = 0;
    if (y < newcoor.Count() - 1 && newcoor[y].X == tempx && newcoor[y].Y == tempy) // compare if there is a Point in the List that is equal with the (tempx,tempy) coordinate
    {
        vector[x].X = tempx;// store the coordinates
        vector[x].Y = tempy;

    }
    break; // this is what I don't understand, I want to exit the loop immediately if the if-condition is true. And add 1 to x so the while loop will update.
}
```

**Tried New Code:**

```
for (int y = 0; y < newcoor.Count() - 1; y++)
            {
                var tempx = centerx + 1;
                var tempy = centery - 1;
                for (int x = 0; x < newcoor.Count() - 1; x++)
                {
                    if (newcoor[y].X == tempx && newcoor[y].Y == tempy)
                    {
                        //vectorPoints.Add(new Point(tempx,tempy));
                        MessageBox.Show("success");

                    }
                }
            }
```

But no messagebox success shows, meaning there was no match. but there must be.

All I need is 4 output that's why I have conditon **while (x <= 3)**

**Update:**

**My centerx = 30 and centery = 28**

And here is my list:

[image: PointsList]

What I want to do is **add 1 to centerx** and **subtract 1 to centery**

from original centerx= 30 and centery= 28, it should be

(31,27)
(32,26)
(33,25)
(34,24)
**(35,23)** <----- This should be the to the one with the same value inside my list, which is shown in the image above.

Comment: just move `break` into `if` block: `if (...) { ... break; }`

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're hoping for here, but there's several problems I can spot anyway;

Firtly, `tempx` and `tempy` will be the same value on each loop, as nothing inside the loop manipulates `centerx` or `centery`.

Secondly, the loop will exit on the first run, as the break statement is not inside the `if {..}` block. Perhaps you meant;

```
if (y < newcoor.Count() - 1 && newcoor[y].X == tempx && newcoor[y].Y == tempy)
{
    vector[x].X = tempx;// store the coordinates
    vector[x].Y = tempy;

    break;  // <-- needs to be inside the if{..} block 
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is, add +1 to centerx and subtract 1 to centery, until that coordinate will have the same value with the points inside my List of Points, which is newcoor. I have updated my code. Please take a look